# goback and GO TO paragraph

Tags: cobol

Is there any way that can let me cancel the effect of a "GO TO" in cobol
Example:

```
    PERFORM PROCEDURE1 THRU E--PROCEDURE1
    display "PERFORM     PROCEDURE2 THRU E--PROCEDURE2"
    PERFORM     PROCEDURE2 THRU E--PROCEDURE2
    GOBACK.

   PROCEDURE1 SECTION.
       display "BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE1"
       PERFORM LECTURE THRU E--LECTURE
       PERFORM ENDD THRU E--ENDD
       display "  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE1"
       CONTINUE.
       EXIT.
   E--PROCEDURE1.
       EXIT.


    LECTURE.
       display "I AM LABEL LECTURE"
       GO TO ENDD
       CONTINUE.
    E--LECTURE.
       EXIT.

    ENDD.
       DISPLAY "I AM LABEL ENDD"
       CONTINUE.
    E--ENDD.
       EXIT.

    PROCEDURE2 SECTION.
       display "BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE2"
       DISPLAY "I AM LABEL PROCEDURE2"
       display "  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE2"
       CONTINUE.
    E--PROCEDURE2.
       EXIT.
```

When this code is executed, i won't see the display "PERFORM     PROCEDURE2 THRU E--PROCEDURE2", beacause when i made a GO TO the paragraph ENDD, the control is permantely transfered into that paragraph and i think there is no way that i can use to goback to the end of proc1 ? am-i wrong ?

@Bill

This is the program that i am trying to translate:

```
GOTO5POW : PROC OPTIONS(MAIN);
DCL FILE001 FILE INPUT RECORD ENV(RECSIZE(15));
DCL CTR1  PIC'99' INIT('0');
DCL CARTE CHAR(15);
CALL PROCEDURE1;
PUT SKIP LIST("PERFORM     PROCEDURE2 THRU E--PROCEDURE2");
CALL PROCEDURE2;
PROCEDURE1: PROC;
      PUT SKIP LIST("BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE1");
      ON ENDFILE(FILE001) GOTO ENDD;
      LECTURE:
      PUT SKIP LIST("I AM LABEL LECTURE");
      READ FILE(FILE001) INTO(CARTE);
      CTR1 = CTR1 + 1;
      PUT SKIP LIST("Record "||CTR1||"=/" || CARTE ||"/");
      IF CARTE="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" THEN GOTO ENDD;
      ENDD:
         PUT SKIP LIST("I AM LABEL ENDD");
      PUT SKIP LIST("  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE1");
END PROCEDURE1;
PROCEDURE2 : PROC;
    PUT SKIP LIST("BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE2");
    PUT SKIP LIST("I AM LABEL PROCEDURE2");

    PUT SKIP LIST("  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE2");
END PROCEDURE2;
END GOTO5POW ;
```

The output is:

```
BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE1
I AM LABEL LECTURE
Record 01=/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/
I AM LABEL ENDD
  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE1
PERFORM     PROCEDURE2 THRU E--PROCEDURE2
BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE2
I AM LABEL PROCEDURE2
  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE2
```

But with cobol, this the generated output:

```
BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE1
I AM LABEL LECTURE
Record 01=/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/
I AM LABEL ENDD
BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE2
I AM LABEL PROCEDURE2
  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE2
```

Comment: Remove `THRU E--PROCEDURE1`. I don't know what nightmare of a program you are trying to create. You don't seem to be aware of the implications of `SECTION` and `THRU` on  a `PERFORM`. This hit-and-miss programming is generating a big pile of PERFORM-spaghetti, which, even if it seems to do what you think you want will be extremely difficult to understand and maintain. Again, go back to your starting-point and show some real code that you are trying to "convert".

Comment: I added what you asked me Mr Bill

Comment: It is not an actual example program. The `GOTO` has as its target the next statement. The program will work identically without the GOTO, as @BruceMartin has in his answer. Somewhere you have some real PL/I code which shows the `LEAVE` and whatever else you want to convert to COBOL.

Answer (score 2):

As bill said, do not use thru. Also use either Procedures or sections; **not both**. The ON ENDFILE(FILE001) sets up exception handler for end-of file

This roughly what your program should be:

```
            03                               pic x value 'N'.
               88 File001-EOF         value 'Y'.
               88 File001-has-data    value 'N'.

       PERFORM PROCEDURE1 
       display "PERFORM     PROCEDURE2 THRU E--PROCEDURE2"
       PERFORM PROCEDURE2 
       GOBACK.

       PROCEDURE1 SECTION.
          display "BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE1"
          display "I AM LABEL LECTURE"
          Read File001
            at end set File001-EOF               to true
          end-read
          if File001-has-data
              compute CTR1 = CTR1 + 1;
          end-if

          DISPLAY "I AM LABEL ENDD"
          display "  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE1"

          EXIT.
       E--PROCEDURE1.
          EXIT.


       PROCEDURE2 SECTION.
          display "BEGIN============PROC PROCEDURE2"
          DISPLAY "I AM LABEL PROCEDURE2"
          display "  ENDD============PROC PROCEDURE2"
          CONTINUE.
       E--PROCEDURE2.
          EXIT.
```

---

For people more familiar with java / c# the

```
ON ENDFILE(FILE001) GOTO ENDD;
```

setups up an exception or error handler for the End-Of-File condition. In java it would be like:

```
try {
   .... 
} catch (endOfFile e) {
   Goto ENDD;
}
```

Comment: Optimised-out the `GO TO`. Can't be helped :-)